# Check if a type parameter is a specific interface

Tags: java, factory

I am writing a factory class that looks like this:

```
public class RepositoryFactory<T> {
    public T getRepository(){
        if(T is IQuestionRepository){ // This is where I am not sure
            return new QuestionRepository();
        }
        if(T is IAnswerRepository){ // This is where I am not sure
            return new AnswerRepository();
        }
    }
}
```

but how can I check it `T` is a type of specified `interface`?

Comment: You can't. Pass a `Class` instance to `getRepository()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to create the `RepositoryFactory` instance by passing in the `Class` object for the generic type.

```
public class RepositoryFactory<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    public RepositoryFactory(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public T getRepository(){
        if(type.isAssignableFrom(IQuestionRepository.class)){ //or type.equals(...) for more restrictive
            return new QuestionRepository();
        }
        ...
    }
```

Otherwise, at runtime, you cannot know the value of the type variable `T`.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! I am still learning Java so I was not sure how to do that.